sequelize-typescript column sub select
I've tried everything I know.
I'm essentially trying to do what would be a column select and set the column value to an array. What would be the easiest way of achieving this?
import { Table, Column, Model, ForeignKey, BelongsTo, HasOne, HasMany, DataType, AfterCreate, AfterInit, AfterFind } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import Competitor from './competitor.model';
import ProductRef from '../models/product-ref.model';
import sequelize from 'sequelize';
import Database from '../db/mysql';

@Table({ tableName: 'model_b', timestamps: true })
export default class ModelB extends Model<ModelB> {
  @Column({ primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true })
  id!: number;

  @Column({
    defaultValue: sequelize.literal('now()')
  })
  createdAt!: Date;

  @Column({
    defaultValue: sequelize.literal('now()')
  })
  updatedAt!: Date;


  // Here is where I want to run a sub query, Something like "select * from table where col like value. And then create an array of these rows.
  @Column({
    type: DataType.VIRTUAL,
    get() {
      return this.getDataValue('modelAs');
    },
    set(value) {
      this.setDataValue('modelAs', value);
    }
  })
  modelAs: ModelA[] = [];

  @AfterInit
  static afterInitHook(instance: ModelA): void {
      
  }

  @AfterFind
  static afterInitHook(instances: ModelB[]): void {
      //Here this returns all instances of the "ModelB". This makes me think what's the point in even having the AfterFind hook at all. I thought the whole point of hooks was to manipulate instance vars of "this" when certain event hooks fire.
  }
}

